# Studying the convergence/divergence of an infinite sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying how to see if a sequence converges or diverges using convergence tests: ratio, comparison, root, integral, limit comparison...

I don't see which convergence test should I apply to this series:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{2^n+n^2}}{3^{n-2}} $$

Comment: Use limit-comparison, noting that $2^n+n^2$ is dominated by $2^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comparison test
$$\sum_{n\geq 5}\frac{\sqrt{2^n+n^2}}{3^{n-2}}\leq\sum_{n\geq 5}\frac{\sqrt{2^n+2^n}}{3^{n-2}}$$

Comment: Really I didn't see Lord comment, but I don't feel good!

Answer (score 1):

Surely $\sqrt{2^n+n^2}< 2^{n+1}$ for any $n\ge 1$

therefore we have

$\dfrac{\sqrt{2^n+n^2}}{3^{n-2}}<2\cdot 3^2\cdot \dfrac{2^n}{3^n}=18\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$

which converges because it's a geometric series with ratio less than $1$

being smaller than a convergent series the given series converges

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Simpler: as it is a series with positive terms, you can use *equivalence* :

$\sqrt{2^n+n^2}\sim_\infty \bigl(\sqrt 2\mkern2mu\bigr)^n$, so
$\;\dfrac{\sqrt{2^n+n^2}}{3^{n-2}}\sim_\infty \dfrac19\biggl(\dfrac{\sqrt 2\mkern2mu}{3}\biggr)^{\!n},\;$
which is a convergent geometric series.